# Why the show/hide div is working in firefox but not in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

Following is the concerned HTML code :

```
<select>
    <option id="show">Traditional class</option>
    <option id="hide">Online class</option>
</select>
<div id="paypal">
    <ul class="checkbox-grid">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="text1" value="value1" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
            <label>All</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="text2" value="value2" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
            <label>Mon</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="text3" value="value3" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
            <label for="text3">Tue</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="text4" value="value4" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
            <label for="text4">Wed</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="text5" value="value5" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
            <label for="text5">Thu</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="text6" value="value6" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
            <label for="text6">Fri</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="text7" value="value7" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
            <label for="text7">Sat</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="text8" value="value8" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
            <label for="text8">Sun</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>hr</option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>min</option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>am</option>
                    <option>pm</option>
                    <option></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>hr</option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>min</option>
                    <option></option>
                    <option></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>am</option>
                    <option>pm</option>
                    <option></option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The respective jQuery code to hide/show div (i.e.`<div  id="paypal">`)is as follows :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#show").click(function() {
            // $("#paypal").removeAttr("style");
            $("#paypal").show();
        });
    }); 
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#hide").click(function() {
            //$("#paypal").attr("style","display:none");
            $("#paypal").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above functionality of hide/show is working perfect in Mozilla firefox but not in Google Chrome. It always shows the `<div id="paypal">`.

Why so?
Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: either close your first `<script>` tag or remove your second.

Comment: `<option>` does not fire a click event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because *option* does not have a click event so you need to use the select's change event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        $('#paypal').toggle(); // if you only have 2 options use toggle
    });
});
```

If you have more you can check the selected option's ID

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        this[this.options.selectedIndex].id === 'show' ? $('#paypal').show() : $('#paypal').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Might need add additional selector(id or class) for `select` element, if there are multiple `select` elements in the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(){
  // $("#paypal").removeAttr("style");
     $("#paypal").show();
  });
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    //$("#paypal").attr("style","display:none");
    $("#paypal").hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

You don't need two script tags, neither two separate calls to `ready`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(){
   // $("#paypal").removeAttr("style");
   $("#paypal").show();
  });

  $("#hide").click(function(){
    //$("#paypal").attr("style","display:none");
    $("#paypal").hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

Use this code

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: 
use the `change` event instead of `click`. [Check this out](http://jsbin.com/motuyu/1/edit?html,js,output). (please remember that jsbin adds `$(document).ready` automatically, you need to add by yourself)

Long answer:
here is an example. Suppose you have this html for the select:

```
<select id="selection">
    <option value="show">Traditional class</option>
   <option value="hide">Online class</option>
</select>
```

Then, you just need this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selection").change(function(){
      if($("#selection").val() == "show"){
        $("#paypal").show();
      }
      else if($("#selection").val() == "hide"){
        $("#paypal").hide();
      }
    });
});
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your HTML first:

```
<select id="display-paypal">
   <option value="show" >Traditional class</option>
   <option value="hide" >Online class</option>
</select>
```

Then, you will modify your javascript as below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#display-paypal").change(function(){  
     if(this.val() == 'show') {
         $("#paypal").show();
     } else {
        $("#paypal").hide();
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help!.Checkout this fiddle link with some changes to your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/bpe54j5a/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#sel').change(function(){
    if(event.srcElement.value== 'Traditional class'){
        $("#paypal").show();
    }
    else{
        $("#paypal").hide();        
    }

});

});
```

Reason i suspect why it worked in mozilla but not in chrome, is may be because of unaligned **script** tag used in your code. Also you are listening to clicking on particular  options of select, which doesn't sound appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector for the `select` element and use it's `.change` jquery function.

```
<select id="vshow">
    <option id="show">Traditional class</option>
    <option id="hide">Online class</option>
</select>
```

Modify your jQuery as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#vshow").change(function(){
   $("#paypal").toggle();
  });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bxjo3wns/.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a short code snippet. 
However toggle now needs an additional migrate file but it is okay to deal with it.

Just create two functions inside your click event-

```
function(){
$('#paypal').show();
},
function(){
$('#paypal').hide();
}
```

**So it-**

```
 $(function(){
     $('button').toggle(
            function(){
            $('#paypal').hide();
            },
            function(){
            $('#paypal').show();
       });
    });
```

**Acts like this-**

http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/3n586z1r/